# How to put a black border around certain dots on a ggplot geom_point plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a geom plot using ggplot for some pathways of interest. I would like to put a black border around certain dots that are significant. -log10 > 1.2, so they are easier to identify. Is there anyway to do this in the package so I do not have to do in an illustrator package after I have produced the image? Thank you kindly for advice.

- **Image of current dot image:**
  [image]
- **Image of raw data:**
  [image]

```
cols <- c("blue",
          "white",
          "red")

li <- c(-2, 2)

D1 <- ggplot(Practice, aes(Practice$case, Practice$pathway, 
      colour = Enrichment_score, size = Practice$ln)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_size(breaks = c(0, 1.2, 1.4), range =  c(0.06,12)) +
  guides(size=guide_legend(title = "-log10(q value)"),
         scale_colour_gradient()) +
  labs(colour = "Enrichment Score") +
  theme_bw()
  
D1 + ggtitle("") +
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Responder vs Non-responder",
                            "Non-responder vs Control", 
                            "Responder vs Control", 
                            "Case vs Control"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I do not have your original data, and you don't have an example graph, I'll use `diamonds` to see if this is want you want.

To "circle" the data point that you want to highlight, we can use an extra `geom_point`, and use some subset of data in it.

In your case, the subset can be like `geom_point(data = subset(Practice, -log10(Enrichment_score) > 1.2), col = "black", stroke = 3, shape = 21)`.

```
library(tidyveres)

cols <- c("blue", "white", "red")
ggplot(diamonds, aes(cut, clarity, 
                    colour = price, size = depth)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.8) + 
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = cols) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  scale_size(breaks = c(0, 1.2, 1.4), range =  c(0.06,12)) +
  guides(size=guide_legend(title = "-log10(q value)"),
         scale_colour_gradient()) +
  labs(colour = "Enrichment Score") +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data = subset(diamonds, depth > 70), col = "black", stroke = 3, shape = 21)
```

[image: geom_point_stroke_with_subset]

Also, you don't need to use the dollar sign `$` to specify column names in `ggplot`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, which may be simpler, is to use shape 21 with `geom_point`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_point(shape = 21,  stroke = 1, aes(colour = disp >= 250, fill = hp)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = "black", `FALSE` = rgb(0,0,0,0)))
```

[image]

The manual colour scale makes the edge of shape 21 either black or transparent. Note the backticks for `TRUE` or `FALSE`.